# How to assign ItemsSource property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, itemssource

Okay, sorry for my previous mess.

The situation is this:
I have two custom objects defined as follows:
MainObject:

```
public class MainObject
{
    private string mainObjectName;
    public string MainObjectName { get { return mainObjectName; } }

    private List<SubObject> subObjectData;
    public List<SubObject> SubObjectData { get { return subObjectData; } }

    public MainObject(string name, List<SubObject> objectData)
    {
        mainObjectName = name;
        subObjectData = objectData;
    }
}
```

SubObject:

```
public class SubObject
{
    private string subObjectName;
    public string SubObjectName { get { return subObjectName; } }

    private List<int> integerData;
    public List<int> IntegerData { get { return integerData; } }

    public SubObject(string name, List<int> data)
    {
        subObjectName = name;
        integerData = data;
    }
}
```

I also have a viewmodel which for simplicity defines some data using those two objects as follows:VM

```
public List<Model.MainObject> VMList = new List<Model.MainObject>()
    {
        new Model.MainObject("MainItem1", new List<Model.SubObject>()
        {
            new Model.SubObject("SubItem1", new List<int>() { 1,6,3}),
            new Model.SubObject("SubItem2", new List<int>() { 5,2,9})
        }),
        new Model.MainObject("MainItem2", new List<Model.SubObject>()
        {
            new Model.SubObject("SubItem1", new List<int>() { 0,3,1}),
            new Model.SubObject("SubItem2", new List<int>() { 7,5,2})
        })
    };
```

now I have the following UI

```
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl Name="MainObjectIC">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding MainObjectName}"/>
                    <ItemsControl Name="SubObjectIC">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding SubObjectName}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

I assign the ItemsSource of the MainObjectIC in the code behind like so:

```
ViewModel.VM dc = new ViewModel.VM();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = dc;
        MainObjectIC.ItemsSource = dc.VMList;
    }
```

I also want to assign the ItemsSource to the SubObjectIC but to do that I have to get that ItemsControl object. And this is what I am trying to achieve.

From what I understood it may be a very very bad and useless to assign the ItemsSource property from the code behind.

Comment: I think a relative source on the binding for the "child" collection should work.  I have only done that for finding ancestor type of window, but I think it will allow many more types.

Comment: there are `{Binding ...}` binding all over the markup. why ItemsSource for `RelicItemsSource` cannot be bound fro xaml?

Comment: yes, but I have no clue how to do it as the RelicItemsSource should depend on the Object bound to the ComponentsItemsSource. Also I think i need bind the DataContext to 'this' instead of my custome object.

Comment: Seems like the wrong approach, but you can use Binding ElementName for this

Comment: so I should be using "Binding ElementName=RelicItemsControl, Path=ItemsSource" or something except I need to bind it to the Collection named 'RelicList'. Never have I ever used a Binding so complex as that. (I kinda hate wpf and prefer doing stuff in code behind)

Comment: The logical way to do it for me was to go like this: 
"Binding ElementName=RelicItemsControl, Path=Tag.RelicList" 
since the Tag is the object that contains the collection needed to be bound.

Comment: _"I kinda hate wpf"_ -- that could be because you are fighting WPF instead of working with it. It is very rare that you should need to refer to a specific control like this. Your question doesn't explain what you're actually trying to do (see [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)), but likely the correct way to deal with this is to declare templates as resources for view model objects, and have the view model objects interact with each other, rather than trying to directly manipulate the UI.

Comment: WPF can be hard to learn, but it works well once one accepts the paradigm shift involved in strong separate of UI and data.

Comment: as for this part: _" I am trying to bind that second collection to the RelicItemsSource"_ -- you should be able to do that in XAML, with the normal `{Binding}` syntax. The `DataContext` for each templated item in the top-level `ItemsControl` is the respective individual object from the top-level collection. If that object has a property that is another collection, just bind the property to the `ItemsSource` property of your inner `ItemsControl`. No need to go rummaging around in the visual tree or reference controls by name, etc.

Comment: If you need help figuring it out, fix your question so it includes a good [mcve] showing clearly what you've tried, and explaining precisely what it is you can't figure out.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Yeah it does feel like it. Also if I try to directly bind it throws a runtime error :'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException', 'Add value to collection of type 'System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection' threw an exception.'. I will clean up the code for a more clear view of the problem. Thanks for the help so far

Comment: @PeterDuniho I update the code and hopefully the problem is clearer now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for improving your code example. It still wasn't quite complete, but it's close enough to be able to provide an answer.

In your example, the main thing missing is to simply add the necessary `{Binding}` expression. In particular:

```
<ItemsControl Name="SubObjectIC" Grid.Column="1"
              ItemsSource="{Binding SubObjectData}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding SubObjectName}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

The context for the item already is an object of type `MainObject` (which is why your `TextBlock` binding works). So all that remains to be done is bind the `ItemsSource` property to the `MainObject.SubObjectData` property.

(I had to add the `Grid.Column` assignment, which appeared to be missing from your example above.)

The above change is completely sufficient to get your example to work as you desire. However, you can also improve the code by using the same basic approach to the top-level control as well. To do so, your `VM.VMList` field needs to be changed to be a property (WPF only binds to properties, not fields):

```
class VM
{
    public List<MainObject> VMList {  get { return _vmList; } }

    private readonly List<MainObject> _vmList = new List<MainObject>()
    {
        new MainObject("MainItem1", new List<SubObject>()
        {
            new SubObject("SubItem1", new List<int>() { 1,6,3}),
            new SubObject("SubItem2", new List<int>() { 5,2,9})
        }),
        new MainObject("MainItem2", new List<SubObject>()
        {
            new SubObject("SubItem1", new List<int>() { 0,3,1}),
            new SubObject("SubItem2", new List<int>() { 7,5,2})
        })
    };
}
```

Then you can just remove the explicit assignment that's in your constructor:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = dc;
}
```

With those changes, your XAML no longer needs to give any of the controls names, and you can bind directly to the relevant properties:

```
<Window x:Class="TestSO42929995WpfNestedData.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestSO42929995WpfNestedData"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <Grid>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding VMList}">
      <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition/>
              <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding MainObjectName}"/>
            <ItemsControl Grid.Column="1"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding SubObjectData}">
              <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding SubObjectName}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
              </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
          </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

A key point that might not be obvious in the above is that every control has a `DataContext`. When you using the `{Binding}` syntax, by default the property path is relative to that context. In the top-level control, the context is what you set it to be in the constructor. But in the individual list item template, the context is the individual data object for that list item, which in your case is the `MainObject` object. So in that context, you just bind to the `SubObjectData` property, just like you bind to the `MainObjectName`. It works exactly the same, and for the same reason.

Comment: Oh, god please kill me, I am such an idiot. Thanks a lot for time wasted

Comment: @George: no need to be so hard on yourself. If you were really an idiot, you wouldn't have been receptive to feedback about your original post and how to improve it (believe me, there are plenty such people on Stack Overflow). And while I suspect there are _similar_ questions on Stack Overflow, I searched for but did not find any that were quite exactly like yours. And even if there are, this one now has a good, simple code example to illustrate both the question and answer, which hardly seems like a waste of time. :)

Comment: Thanks for the support and great attitude :)